# How could I reduce word2vec dimention?

Tags: doc2vec

I would like to reduce 100 dimention Doc2Vector to 2 dimention with the vector of each sentence will be the same even if multiple executions.
I tried using t-SNE, Umap, PCA etc., but the vector of specific sentence will be changed after multiple trials of these method. How I could reduce word2vec dimention?
I wodld like to find the way that would not change the result of specific sentence vector after multiple trials.
Please let me know to do that/

tetsuya nobuhara,  nobutetsu@andaze.com

Comment: Which algorithm do you mean by your references to "Doc2Vector", "word2vec" and "doc2vec"? Do you mean 2 executions of just the dimensionality-reduction step, or repeated executions of the complete training (or inference) cycle that created the original full-width vectors/vector-model? Why do you want such low-dimensional vectors, which generally *won't* have any of the benefits for which people usually use these algorithms?

Comment: Please use a spelling checker.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python gensim, and its script is below.
In the dimention reduction step of Umap, multiple trials create different results. I would plot each person's browsing activities from web log's of 'Title' data like this
"#58 pattern_C by TomoyukiHata · Pull Request #61 · andaze/WebCorporate · GitHub" to understand who visit which Web Site.
So, I vectorize Title list by Doc2vec and reduce vector by Umap. The result from Doc2Vec is stable, however the result form Umap will change by multiple trials. I hope Title's 2 dimention plot could be stable in every trials.

```
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec
model = Doc2Vec.load("jawiki.doc2vec.dbow300d.model")  # pre trained model

model.random.seed(0)

Y = []
for i in range(190000):
    Y.append(list(model.infer_vector(sentences[i])))    
    Y = np.array(Y)

## Reduce to 2 dimention
import umap
umap_data = umap.UMAP(random_state=0, n_neighbors=50, min_dist=0.3,
                      n_components=2).fit_transform(Y)

## Plot 2 dimention scatter
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(umap_data, x='x', y='y', hover_data=["Title"], color ='User')
```